# How to turn a simple csv into a line graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I created a simple csv file with numbers that approach pi and I would like to create and store the output as a png. I have a very simple csv, each tow contains the number I want to graph and

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from decimal import Decimal

def create_png():

df = pd.read_csv('sticks.csv', names=["xstk", "stk"])

sumdf = df.sum(0)
num1 = sumdf['xstk']
num2 = sumdf['stk']
total = num1 + num2

aproxpi = [(2*float(total))/num1]

with open('aproxpi.csv', 'a') as pifile:
    piwriter = csv.writer(pifile, delimiter= ' ')
    piwriter.writerow(aproxpi)

Piplot = pd.read_csv('aproxpi.csv', names=['~Pi'])

#Piplot.groupby('~Pi')


Piplot.plot(title='The Buffon Needle Experiment')   




if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_png()
```

When I run this code nothing happens. If I use the show method on the AxesSubPlot I raise an exception. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `plt.show()` to actually see the plot.

Comment: Thank you, I attempted to call show() but did not realize it was a method of plt.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems very incomplete - is there more you can give us?

It may be that `Piplot.plot` needs to have x and y specified, instead of simply a title. I believe that you need to create a new plot object and pass the data into it, rather than calling `data.plot()` as you are now. See the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot).

Additionally, taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992697/how-to-read-the-date-time-field-from-the-csv-file-and-plot-a-graph-accordingly-i?rq=1) may help.

Comment: I have now edited it to show the whole code, I will try to do that now.