# Importing and plotting mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss data in PyPlot

Tags: python, date, csv

I am new to Python (using 2.7.11) and am trying to make a simple plot. I have opened and read my file columns into lists. I want to plot Date_Time (format of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) versus Data (decimal numbers). I am getting an error from the date/time column, and I know I have to convert it into something that Pyplot can read, but I am unsure how to do so. My current code is below. Thanks!

```
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('filename.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   for row in reader:
      for (k,v) in row.items():
         columns[k].append(v)
```

This left me with the following lists: columns['Date_Time'] and columns['Data']

Sample of the CSV:

Date         Time            Date_Time          AOT_500

5/3/2016    22:29:12    05/03/2016  22:29:12    0.346481

5/3/2016    22:37:32    05/03/2016  22:37:32    0.353119

Error: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 05/03/2016 22:29:12

Comment: First, welcome to SO. Can you please add a sample of the CSV and the exact error you get?

Comment: What does your `Date_Time` data look like? You will probably want to convert that string into a native Python datetime object. You can take a look at a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4993072/426790) as well.

Comment: The error says: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 05/03/2016 22:29:12.

Comment: And the Date_Time data is the form mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss, as seen in the error message above. Thanks for the help!